# how to go around "keyword can't be an expression" when updating in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sql-update, keyword, cycle

i have a following statement:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(Somedatabase.update().where(somecriteria==somecriteriavalue).values(name = somevalue))
```

and it works, but when i try replace it by following:

```
D={1: "name"}
print(D[1])
conn.execute(Somedatabase.update().where(somecriteria==somecriteriavalue).values(D[1]) = somevalue))
```

Then, I got an error: "keyword can't be an expression". How can I go around to be able use it in cycle?

So far i figured only

```
text="conn.execute(Somedatabase.update().where(somecriteria == somecriteriavalue).values("+(D[1])+" = \"somevalue\"))"
eval(text)
```

But i would prefer to not using eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use a dictionary as a parameter for values:

```
D={1: "name"}
print(D[1])
conn.execute(
    Somedatabase.update().where(
        somecriteria==somecriteriavalue
    ).values({
        D[1]: somevalue,
    })
)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ValuesBase.values

Comment: Oh, it works. I thought that dictionaries should work, but i am very new with them, so  you have my thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, as a way of saying thanks, you could accept the answer?

Comment: done, sorry i am new on stack so I dont know all the things yet :)